# Http post request data size is much bigger than I really uploaded

Tags: http-post

I requested about 40MB of data through http request.

But when I saw the content-length of actually requested data is more than 140M.

And when I requested about 20MB, the actual requested size is 90MB.

I want to know why.

Thank you for any answers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJvnf.png)

I was expecting that when I upload 20M, the actual size should be less than 30M.